# Why does mov fail to set dynamic section sizes when used on a function using GCC

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, system-calls, intel

I'm working on implementing threads in x86_64 Intel assembly, and when using GCC, I receive the following error on compilation, even when I use the -fPIE flag.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc7xDzsl.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The assembly compiles without errors when I remove the following line, where f is a label.

```
mov rdi, f
```

I've attempted a number of things I've seen on here, such as `mov rdi, [f]` and `mov rdi, offset f`, but I haven't been able to work out an answer. I'm not massively familiar with GCC or x86, so I'm probably missing something. I'll put the code below here, if you have any ideas. Thanks!

```
.intel_syntax noprefix 
.globl main 
.section .rodata 
.text
f:                 # Exits thread
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60
    syscall

main: 
    call create_thread_stack
    pop rsi                    # --
    sub rsi, 8                 # | Put function pointer onto
    mov rdi, f                 # | new stack
    push rdi                   # --
    pop qword ptr [rsi]        # Put function pointer onto new stack
    mov rdi, -2147479808       # Flags
    mov rax, 56                # Sys_clone
    syscall
    ret

create_thread_stack:    # Mmaps stack for cloned process
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, 4194304    # Size of stack
    mov rdx, 3          
    mov r10, 290
    mov r9, 0
    mov r8, -1
    mov rax, 9          # Sys_mmap
    syscall
    add rax, 4194304
    push rax            # Return base pointer of new stack
    ret
```

Comment: You want `lea rdi, [f+rip]` Also note that the `push rax; ret` will crash.

Comment: `create_thread_stack` won't work as intended, because the near call also uses the stack. So `push rax` then `ret` will jump to the address in `rax`, not return to your `main` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Jester , does that mean that f just gives the offset from the current instruction? @ecm , is there a way to push onto the stack before returning, or is it just better to keep it in `rax` until getting back to the calling function?

Comment: Yes and yes (that is the normal calling convention)

Comment: @FlappyToucan `[foo+rip]` is notation to indicate that you want to address `foo` in a RIP-relative way.  The address of `foo` is translated by the assembler into an offset from `rip`.  So `[foo]` and `[foo+rip]` will access the same memory in position-dependent binaries.